# Is there a way to save visual voicemails with a better filename pattern or attach metadata to the resulting file?

Tags: visual-voicemail

I am preparing to switch carriers and have a bunch of visual voicemails I do not want to lose.  The simplest way to do this appears to save them to a file before switching carriers.

The problem is that when saving them, by default my iphone saves them with the filename "voicemail-bigRandomNumber.m4a" with no metadata.

I am wondering if there is some way to automatically change the filename to something that contains critical metadata, like "voicemail-phone#-date-time.m4a" or embed this metadata into the actual m4a file.

If there is a third party tool that could do this, I am open to it as well.